ASP.NET - How to accept a JSON object in a controller
I am trying to send an object in JSON format to my controller - however, the object's properties appear to be null. While the payload is being sent, there just isn't any data-pairing going on across the request.
I have not seen a lot of recent solutions to this, mostly from 10+ years ago, and was hoping someone can lead me to a modern solution of this problem.
I have a model:
public class Expenses
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

I create a similar object in JS 
//create the object
let expense = {
    id: "listOrder"+listOfExpensesCounter,
    Month: formData.month,
    Week: formData.week,
    Type: category[0],
    Amount: formData.amount === "" ? 0 : formData.amount,
    Date: formData.date === "" ? getCurrentDate() : formData.date,
    Description: formData.description
}

I then proceed with an AJAX call to the controller:
function ajaxCall(expense) {
    const obj = JSON.stringify(expense);
    $.ajax({

        url:'/Expenses/Create',

        // Type of Request
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "Post",
        data: obj,
        dataType: "json",

        // Function to call when to
        // request is ok 
        success: function (data) {},

        // Error handling 
        error: function (error) {}
    });
}

My Controller:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Expenses expense)
{
    try
    {
 
        Expenses newExpense = new Expenses
        {
            Month = expense.Month,
            Week = expense.Week,
            CategoryId = expense.CategoryId,
            Amount = expense.Amount,
            Date = expense.Date,
            Description = expense.Description                
         };

        
        _db.expensesRepository.Add(newExpense);
        _db.Save();
        return this.Ok($"hello world");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return this.Ok($"hello world error");
    }
}


Does the problem persist if you don't use JSON.stringify?

Yes, it does persist David.

Seems your class that you have created doesn't match the object you create
public class Expenses
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public float Amount { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}

The object you create includes:
let expense = {
            id: "listOrder"+listOfExpensesCounter,
            Month: formData.month,
            Week: formData.week,
            Type: category[0],
            Amount: formData.amount === "" ? 0 : formData.amount,
            Date: formData.date === "" ? getCurrentDate() : formData.date,
            Description: formData.description
        }

The object you create is missing. CategoryId, category and you are passing a Parameter called Type which is not specified in your C# class Expenses, and assigning the value category[0] to it. Check those object attributes with your C# class accordingly.
Ensure the property names in the JavaScript object (Id, Month, Week, CategoryId, Amount, Date, Description) match exactly with the properties in your Expenses C# model.
Also in your Endpoint in C# make sure to add [FromBody]:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Expenses expense)
{
    try
    {
        Expenses newExpense = new Expenses
        {
            Month = expense.Month,
            Week = expense.Week,
            CategoryId = expense.CategoryId,
            Amount = expense.Amount,
            Date = expense.Date,
            Description = expense.Description
        };

        _db.expensesRepository.Add(newExpense);
        _db.Save();
        return this.Ok("hello world");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return this.Ok("hello world error");
    }
}


Thanks, this suggestion worked, feels good to get this ball rolling again.  For anyone having this issue in the future and looking for a solution, [FormBody] only worked for me when i used JSON.Stringify on the JS object.  Moreover, the JS object needed to exactly match the model I was sending it to in the ASP.Net Controller, this means the property names and types need to match.

Appreciate if you can mark it as the correct answer and giving an upvote for love for the community :-)

try to add the FromBody Attribute like this
Create([FromBody] Expenses expense)


This doesn't work either.  I receive an error:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Solved:  [FormBody] only worked for me when i used JSON.Stringify on the JS object.  Moreover, the JS object needed to exactly match the model I was sending it to in the ASP.Net Controller, this means the property names and types need to match.  My model did not match the JSON object, so I needed to create a new model to match it and use that to catch the object in the controller.

you dont need to fill in all the fields only if its not nullable. you can make the int types nullable than you dont need to fill it in

i think you don't need to do JSON.stringify() you can directly pass json object
function ajaxCall(expense) {
            $.ajax({

                url:'/Expenses/Create',
                // Type of Request
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: "Post",
                data: expense,
                dataType: "json",

                // Function to call when to
                // request is ok 
                success: function (data) {},

                // Error handling 
                error: function (error) {}
            });
        }

Also check the upper case and lower case

Thanks for the help Pranjal, but I did need to convert it to a JSON object in the end among other things.
